# sql statement: count by date range

Tags: sql, date, count, range

Say I have a following table

## license_num (varchar)--------checkout_datetime (datetime)

ABC-123--------------------------------------------2017-12-29 00:07:00

ABC-123-------------------------------------------                  2017-12-30 00:10:00

XYZ-456-------------------------------------------                  2017-12-30 00:10:00

XYZ-456-------------------------------------------                  2017-12-31 00:11:00

**I need a SQL statement that produce the following result:**

## LicenseNumber--------12/29---12/30---12/31---TotalOfWeek

ABC-123-----------------------------------1-------------1-------------0------------------2

XYZ-456-----------------------------------0--------------1------------1------------------2

How do I write such SQL statement?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: please include your attempts as well.

Comment: What happens if the range should be bigger than 3 days?  Do you expect to have so many dates across columns?

Comment: Please learn how to format your posts

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. :) I got it right...

```
   SELECT *,CONVERT(Varchar(10),
  (DATEPART(MM,checkout_datetime)))+'/'+CONVERT(Varchar(10),
  (DATEPART(DD,checkout_datetime)))  AS NewColName,1 AS Count
  INTO #TempPivotTab2
  FROM TransTable

  SELECT *
  FROM
   (
   SELECT license_num,NewColName,Count
   FROM   #TempPivotTab2 
   ) AS SourceTable
   PIVOT
   (
   SUM(Count)
   FOR NewColName IN ([12/29],[12/30],[12/31])
   )Piv
```